# Problema com fopen

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents

Este ficheiro está a executar a sua função na perfeição, mas está a devolver alguns erros e gostaria de conseguir corrigí-los. Preciso de saber se tenho que usar o `fopen` e o `file_get_contents` pois não estou a conseguir anular nenhum.

```php
# /pasta/copy.php 
<?php
$original = fopen('/pasta/copy.txt','r+');
$ip = fopen('/pasta/origin.txt','r');
$ip = file_get_contents('/pasta/origin.txt','r');
$copia = fopen('/pasta/ok.txt','w+');
if ($original) {
    while(true) {
        $linha = fgets($original);
        if ($linha==null) break;
        if(preg_match("/ASSunto/", $linha)) {
            $string .= str_replace("ASSunto", $ip, $linha);
        } else {
            $string.= $linha;   #**Linha 13**
        }
    }
    rewind($copia);
    ftruncate($copia, 0);
    fwrite($copia, $string);
    fclose($original);
    fclose($copia);
    fclose($ip);    #**Linha 21**
}
?>
```

E os erros são os seguintes:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: string in /pasta/copy.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /pasta/copy.php on line 21
```

O ficheiro `copy.txt`.

```
# /pasta/copy.txt
Assunto para primeira linha
ASSunto
```

O ficheiro `origin.txt`.

```
# /pasta/origin.txt
Assunto para segunda linha
```

O ficheiro `ok.txt` fica assim.

```
# /pasta/ok.txt
Assunto para primeira linha
Assunto para segunda linha
```

Comment: A 4 e 5 linha fazem a mesma coisa. O primeiro aviso indica que a variável `$string` não foi definida, você está usando o operador de concatenação `.=` em uma variável não que não foi inicializada. Abaixo de `$copia = ...` declare: `$string = "";`. O segundo aviso é gerado por causa do conflito nas linhas 4 e  5.

Comment: Ao retirar uma das linhas 4 ou 5 passa a escrever um erro no ficheiro `ok.txt` e não estou a perceber em relação à `string` ao fazer a substituição deixa de funcionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: string in ..

O primeiro erro é gerado porque não foi declarado a variável `string`, você está tentando concatenar um valor a uma variável não existente.

> PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in ..

O segundo erro é gerado devido as linhas *4* e *5*, ou você utiliza `fopen` ou `file_get_contents`. Está sendo atribuído a variável `ip` o resultado da função `file_get_contents` e não o ponteiro do arquivo aberto por `fopen`.

Se optar por utilizar as funções [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) e [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php) ao invés de [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php) e [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php), o seu código pode ficar assim:

```php
<?php

$original = file_get_contents('/pasta/copy.txt');
$ip = file_get_contents('/pasta/origin.txt');
$copia = '/pasta/ok.txt';

if ($original === false){
    echo "Não foi possível ler o arquivo";
    exit;
}

$string = str_replace('ASSunto', $ip, $original);

if (file_put_contents($copia, $string) === false){
    echo "Erro ao gravar no arquivo ". $copia;
} else {
    echo "Operação realizada com sucesso.";
}

?>
```

Não é necessário afirmar com [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) se uma palavra é existente ou não no arquivo, o [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) se encarrega de procurar e substituir *todas* as ocorrências desta palavra.

Se o arquivo especificado em `file_put_contents` não existir, ele será criado, se existir, será sobrescrito.

Comment: Poderias dar-me um exemplo que não escrevesse nada em caso de erro e que fecha-se os ficheiros no fim de utilizados é que este ficheiro vai correr de 2 em 2 minutos e acho que ele vai alterar um pouco o `buffers` da maquina de deixar tantos ficheiros abertos.

Comment: @RjpServidor Não é necessário fechar o *handle* aberto por  `file_get_contents`, ele lê um arquivo e o fecha depois automaticamente. Veja se com [**esse código**](https://ideone.com/2ALlKL) funciona bem para você, *é praticamente o mesmo script da resposta*.